# Cannot get child element's href value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Being spoiled by jQuery for so long, now I'd like to rewrite this line in vanilla javascript:

```
let slug = $(this).children().find('.pjt').attr('href');
```

What I tried (among others) is:

```
 const goToPage = (e) => {
     var slug = e.target.querySelector(".pjt").attr("href");
    console.log("slug is:", slug);
    //window.location.href = slug;
   };
```

But I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: e.target.querySelector(...).attr is not a function
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Use [getAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) instead of `attr`. Check out [You might not need jQuery](https://youmightnotneedjquery.com/) to find (vanilla) JS equivalent functions for your jQuery code

Comment: I definitly need to read that. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Use `e.target.querySelector(".pjt").href`. No need to work with the attribute, just use the element's API!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens to most of us, use `getAttribute` in Vanilla JS

```
e.target.querySelector(".pjt").getAttribute('href')
```